# Could not connect newly created SQL Server database using pyodbc

Tags: sql-server, python-2.7, pyodbc

I have configured a new SQL Server 2017.XXX instance in my Windows 10. Then, created a new database called `CUSTOMER_DEVICES`. I tried to connect to database using pyodbc. I could not and got below error:

> Error - pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', u'[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]

When I use the same code in existing production server it works. Code below

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={SQL Server};Server=localhost;Database=CUSTOMER_DEVICES;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor = conn.cursor()
print(cursor)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if SQL server Configuration Management is configured. Enable TCP, IP. Check below link [Check here](https://www.blackbaud.com/files/support/infinityinstaller/content/installermaster/tkenablenamedpipesandtcpipconnections.htm)